# Get Model in onAfterRendering Method in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have created a json model in Manifest.json file. I want to access this model in onAfterRendering method. I tried below mentioned ways to get the data.

```
var oModel1 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("shipData");
     var oModel2 = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("shipData") ;

     var oModel3 = this.getView().getModel("shipData");
```

And results are oModel1 and oModel3 is created but there is no data when I am trying to get with getData method.

oModel2 is undefined.

How can I get the data from my model in onAfterRendering method?

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not always get data from your JSONModel in the onAfterRendering method. This is very likely due to the fact that the JSON service request defined in your manifest.json is not yet complete. Due to the asynchronous nature of the request you will have to wait until the request is complete. One way would be to attach a request completion event handler on the model.

```
var oModel1 = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("shipData");
oModel1.attachRequestCompleted(function(event){
   //Run code when request is complete
   var oModel = event.getSource();
   var data = oModel.getData();
});
```